# How to prevent nested function failures being missed in bash

Tags: bash

The following code:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -Eeuo pipefail
shopt -s huponexit
shopt -s inherit_errexit

function child_function {
    return 1
}
function parent_function {
    child_function
    echo "parent noticed child exit code as $?"
}
function grandparent_function {
    local ec
    ec=0 && parent_function || ec="$?"
    echo "grandparent noticed parent exit code as $ec"
}

grandparent_function
```

Will surprisingly output:

```
parent noticed child exit code as 1
grandparent noticed parent exit code as 0
```

---

Changing the code to:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -Eeuo pipefail
shopt -s huponexit
shopt -s inherit_errexit

function child_function {
    return 1
}
function parent_function {
    child_function || return "$?"
    echo "parent noticed child exit code as $?"
}
function grandparent_function {
    local ec
    ec=0 && parent_function || ec="$?"
    echo "grandparent noticed parent exit code as $ec"
}

grandparent_function
```

Returns the expected result of:

```
grandparent noticed parent exit code as 1
```

Is there an additional setting that I need to set to fix this? Or is this a bug in bash?

---

The reason I believe it is a bug, is that changing the code to not use the `|| ec="$?"` will respect the `-e/errexit` option (Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status) and have each failed function exit immediately:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -Eeuo pipefail
shopt -s huponexit
shopt -s inherit_errexit

function child_function {
    return 1
}
function parent_function {
    child_function
    echo "parent noticed child exit code as $?"
}
function grandparent_function {
    parent_function
    echo "grandparent noticed parent exit code as $?"
}

grandparent_function
```

Outputs nothing and returns exit code 1

Comment: What version of bash are you running? I'm getting the correct output for both the 1st and 2nd script. The third script exits because of `set -e`.

Comment: What is the difference between 1st and 2nd script?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Made a copy paste mistake... the first script was the same as the second script. I've fixed the first script and now it produces the problem.

Comment: It's not a bug.  It's a feature.  Calling `parent_function` in a conditional context disables `set -e` for it, and everything that it calls.  There is no way to get around  that.  In general, you cannot depend on `set -e` to catch errors.  See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Comment: @pjh interesting... the unfortunate part about this is that if I were to put `parent_function` in its own `.bash` file with the same `set -e` then it would all work as expected, it's only when it is all in one file the disabling of `set -e` has a noticeable impact. Is there another way to get the failure code of a failed function without modifying the failed function?

Comment: @balupton, see [What is the proper way to detect shell exit code when errexit option set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9629710/4154375).

Comment: Thank you, I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/70992989/130638 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447519/50703 — reviewing them now.

Comment: Okay, came up with a solution that didn't require modifying anything but the conditional, thank you all for your help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76861665/130638

Comment: Simple solution: do not use `set -e`, it is a broken concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters:

- [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)
- [kamilcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)
- [pjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4154375/pjh)

And these supporting resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201766/130638
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70992989/130638
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447519/50703
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645365/50703
- [Why is bash errexit not behaving as expected in function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19789102/130638)
- https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=537

I created this workaround for the question's code sample using the subshell technique:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

function child_function {
    return 1
}
function parent_function {
    child_function
    echo "parent noticed child exit code as $?"
}
function grandparent_function {
    local ec=0
    set +e; (set -e; parent_function); ec="$?"; set -e
    echo "grandparent noticed parent exit code as $ec"
}

grandparent_function
```

However, the subshell technique prevents side effects, as modifications do not escape the subshell.

I spent a few more days on this issue, and created a gist with various techniques, including one that works with side effects:

https://gist.github.com/balupton/21ded5cefc26dc20833e6ed606209e1b